# R - Flexible conditions

Tags: r

I have the folowing R statement. Basically it goes through the entire matchesData data frame and checks if the conditions are matched for each row.

If it matches, put a '1' at matchesData$isRedPreferredLineup.

```
matchesData$isRedPreferredLineup <- ifelse((matchesData$redTop==red_poplist[1] & 
                                              matchesData$redADC==red_poplist[2] & 
                                              matchesData$redJungle==red_poplist[3] & 
                                              matchesData$redSupport==red_poplist[4] & 
                                              matchesData$redMiddle==red_poplist[5]  & 
                                              matchesData$YearSeason==Season), 1, 
                                           matchesData$isRedPreferredLineup)
```

However, now I need the condition to be flexible. Meaning, if

```
matchesData$redTop==red_poplist[1]
matchesData$redADC==red_poplist[2]
matchesData$redJungle==red_poplist[3]
```

conditions are matched, or if

```
matchesData$redJungle==red_poplist[3]
matchesData$redSupport==red_poplist[4]
matchesData$redMiddle==red_poplist[5]
```

conditions are matched, or any other permutation comprising 3 or more of the following conditions are matched, I would like to put '1' at matchesData$isRedPreferredLineup.

```
(matchesData$redTop==red_poplist[1] & 
matchesData$redADC==red_poplist[2] & 
matchesData$redJungle==red_poplist[3] & 
matchesData$redSupport==red_poplist[4] & 
matchesData$redMiddle==red_poplist[5]  & 
matchesData$YearSeason==Season)
```

How can I do so in a vectorized ifelse statement like this? 
Or is there a better way to do this?

Please bear with me, I am pretty new to R. Thanks.

Comment: could you provide a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1):

You could vectorise the `TRUE`/`FALSE` statements like this:

```
my.conditions <- cbind(matchesData$redTop==red_poplist[1], matchesData$redADC==red_poplist[2], 
                 matchesData$redJungle==red_poplist[3], matchesData$redSupport==red_poplist[4],
                 matchesData$redMiddle==red_poplist[5], matchesData$YearSeason==Season)
```

Then you could consider `S1 <- rowSums(my.conditions)` which will give you the number of `TRUE`s in `my.conditions` and then (<s>your final condition would boil down to `ifelse(S1 > 2, 1, ...)`</s>) consider the following:

```
matchesData$isRedPreferredLineup[which(S1 > 2)] <- 1
```

Comment: I tried something like this ... applied the sum is the number of matches of this set in the entire table, which was like 128 or so.

Comment: I edited my answer: I used `cbind()` instead of `c()` and `rowSums()` instead of `sum()`. This might help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this coud work:

```
selectIndex <- apply(matchesData,1,function(row){
  sum(c(row['redTop']     == red_poplist[1],
        row['redADC']     == red_poplist[2],
        row['redJungle']  == red_poplist[3],
        row['redSupport'] == red_poplist[4],
        row['redMiddle']  == red_poplist[5],
        row['YearSeason'] == Season) > 3)
})
matchesData$isRedPreferredLineup[selectIndex] <- 1
```